# Django paginator en AJAX

Tags: django, json

Estoy tratando de retornar los elementos de la tabla `professionals` y la siguiente pagina, ambos datos en un JSON. El problema se presenta cuando veo el JSON que se retorna: mi modelo de professionals es un string, no un arreglo de objetos. Aquí dejo mi código:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    professionals = Professionals.objects.defer('id_card')
    paginator = Paginator(professionals, 2)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        professionals = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        professionals = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        professionals = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    data_response = {}
    data_response['professionals'] = serializers.serialize("json", professionals)
    data_response['next_page'] = professionals.next_page_number() if (professionals.has_next()) else -1
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data_response), content_type = "application/json")
    return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')
```

[image: Así es como retorna la información]

Me gustaría que sea retornada como `currentProfessional` el cual lo hice a mano para mostrar.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El serializer de django, por defecto, retorna un string, es decir lo que hace es generarte un string con los datos del queryset o lista de objetos que le pases, por lo cual desde python no podria acceder a el como lo harías como con un diccionario normal de la forma:

```
...
print(professionals[0]['model'])
...
```

Sin embargo, conociendo ya que es un string, hay que buscar alternativas para poder pasar ese string a JSON, y la mejor forma es desde el front, en el método donde recibes la respuesta del servidor por la petición AJAX:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    // puede hacerse así si usas jQuery
    var professionals = $.parseJSON(data);
    // de lo contrario, hacer como propones
    var professionals = JSON.parse(data);
    // sigues trabajando con tus datos como un objeto de javascript
}
...
```

Lo cual evalua el string y lo transforma a un objeto javascript, para trabajar con mayor comodidad